# In Spy++, what value is the control's name?

Tags: c#, .net-4.5, ui-automation, spy++

I'm using System.Windows.Automation to get some UI control text values from labels in a group box. I'm trying to use spy++ to get the control names I'm looking for.

[image]

```
AutomationElement Root = AutomationElement.RootElement;
AutomationElement MainForm = Root.FindFirst(TreeScope.Descendants,new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.AutomationIdProperty,"control name im looking for"));
```

What value represents what I would be searching for? For example would I change it to...
    ...AutomationIdProperty,"Window 00031BB0"));

I'm not sure what all the information given by spy++ actually represents.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: I don't think Spy++ has anything to do with UI Automation.

Comment: With Spy++ you can highlight individual controls by right clicking. It seems like Spy++ must use the control's name to highlight it. I'm just looking for a way to identify a specific control that will work as the AutomationIdProperty.

Comment: @SLaks Do You know of another way this may be possible?

Comment: There's [ManagedSpy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163617.aspx) but I don't know how/if this would work with System.Windows.Automation. Are you doing this for some kind of UI testing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking for the [UI Automation Inspector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318521%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), part of the Windows SDK, which shows the complete UI automation tree.